# link is not clickable when i hover over #button container

Tags: css

i want to make overlay on hover button, i made it but learn more link did'nt appear when i hover over the button container, so i tried change its position as show in code below and it's appear, but it's not clickable, what wrong in my code or how can i show the clickable link in another way?

```css
.container{
    width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.overlay{
    background-color: grey;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 3%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    transition: width 0.6s ease-out;

}

.container:hover .overlay{
    width: 100%;
}

.overlay a{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}

#button-container{
   visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin:70px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

#button-container:after{
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.container:hover #button-container{
    visibility: visible;
}

#button-container:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}

#learn-more{
    transition:all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

#button-container:hover #learn-more{
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    color:black;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class ="container"> 
       <img src="3.jpeg" alt="">
       <div class="overlay">
           <a href="#" class="social">facebook</a>
           <a href="#" class="social">twitter</a>
           <a href="#" class="social">instagram</a>
           <div id="button-container">
            <a id="learn-more" >learn more</a>
            <!-- <div id="button-overlay"></div> -->
           </div>
          
       </div>

       
    </div>
    
</body>
```

how can i do it in another way?

Comment: You need an `href`, like this: `<a id="learn-more" href="/learn.html">learn more</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

`<a id="learn-more" href="#">learn more</a>`

because you need `href` to link become clickable and if you add `href=""` page will reload

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put href attribute for your a tag

```
<a id="learn-more" href="YOUR_LINK"></a>
```